# How can i fix that my message doesn't get decrypted

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, discord.py

I am trying to make an encrypt and decrypt command for my discord bot, however the message doesnt seem to get decrypted

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
from collections.abc import Sequence

def make_sequence(seq):
    if seq is None:
        return ()
    if isinstance(seq, Sequence) and not isinstance(seq, str):
        return seq
    else:
        return (seq,)

def message_check(channel=None, author=None, content=None, ignore_bot=True, lower=True):
    channel = make_sequence(channel)
    author = make_sequence(author)
    content = make_sequence(content)
    if lower:
        content = tuple(c.lower() for c in content)
    def check(message):
        if ignore_bot and message.author.bot:
            return False
        if channel and message.channel not in channel:
            return False
        if author and message.author not in author:
            return False
        actual_content = message.content.lower() if lower else message.content
        if content and actual_content not in content:
            return False
        return True
    return check

@bot.command()
async def encrypt(ctx):
    user = ctx.author
    await user.send("Please enter the message to decrypt.")
    response = await bot.wait_for('message', check=message_check(channel=ctx.author.dm_channel))
    message = response.content
    encoded = message.encode()
    key = Fernet.generate_key()
    f = Fernet(key)
    encrypted = f.encrypt(encoded)
    await ctx.author.send("This is your encrypted message:")
    await ctx.author.send(encrypted)
    await ctx.author.send("This is the key to decrypt the message:")
    await ctx.author.send(key)


@bot.command()
async def decrypt(ctx):
    user = ctx.author
    await user.send("Please enter the encrypted message.")
    response = await bot.wait_for('message', check=message_check(channel=ctx.author.dm_channel))
    encrypted = response.content
    await user.send("Please enter the decryption key:")
    response = await bot.wait_for('message', check=message_check(channel=ctx.author.dm_channel))
    key = response.content
    f = Fernet(key)
    decrypted = f.decrypt(encrypted)
    decoded = decrypted.decode()
    await user.send(decoded)
    print(decoded)
```

I tried to check if the message even gets decrypted with the `print(decoded)` at the end but it doesn't print anything.
I also checked if all the other variables work with print(), and all work except decoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with the way you are encoding and decoding the messages. You need to encode the message and key when using `decrypt`, and you can optionally decode the message and key when using `encrypt` to have it as a normal string and not `b'...'` when sending to the user.

The below modification works, but note that since `message_check` is not known, I commented out the areas where it is used.

```
@bot.command()
async def encrypt(ctx):
    user = ctx.author
    await user.send("Please enter the message to decrypt.")
    response = await bot.wait_for('message') # , check=message_check(channel=ctx.author.dm_channel))
    message = response.content
    encoded = message.encode()
    key = Fernet.generate_key()
    f = Fernet(key)
    encrypted = f.encrypt(encoded)
    await ctx.author.send("This is your encrypted message:")
    await ctx.author.send(encrypted.decode())
    await ctx.author.send("This is the key to decrypt the message:")
    await ctx.author.send(key.decode())


@bot.command()
async def decrypt(ctx):
    user = ctx.author
    await user.send("Please enter the encrypted message.")
    response = await bot.wait_for('message') # , check=message_check(channel=ctx.author.dm_channel))
    encrypted = response.content.encode()
    await user.send("Please enter the decryption key:")
    response = await bot.wait_for('message') # , check=message_check(channel=ctx.author.dm_channel))
    key = response.content.encode()
    f = Fernet(key)
    decrypted = f.decrypt(encrypted)
    decoded = decrypted.decode()
    await user.send(decoded)
    print(decoded)
```